# Stop Blob URL from expiring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am uploading images to the blob store.  I have copied the example 
from 
[here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html).

The only problem I encounter is: If I load the page with the form, and 
not immediately submit the image.  The URL can expire and when I do 
try and load the image I get an error page.  How can I check to see if 
the URL has expired and refresh the URL without the user knowing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the work around is getting the Blob URL when the user submits the form.  This way you know that the URL can't expire.

Using JQuery:

```
$.get("/blobUrl", function(data){
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").attr('action', data);
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").submit();
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").hide();
    $("#loadingImg").show();
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution I could come up with too, it does resolve the issue and also resolves the navigate back issue as described here: http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/just-in-time-blobstore-upload-urls

Comment: Can you give a slightly more fleshed out example? I'm not sure where to put this code. Is it part of the form submit? Is it some function attached to the button? Sorry I'm not a jquery expert.

Comment: This code would be used when the user clicks the upload button and would look something like $("#uploadButton").click(function(){$.get("/blobUrl", function(data){
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").attr('action', data);
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").submit();
    $("#changeProfilePictureForm").hide();
    $("#loadingImg").show();
}); });

Answer (score 0):

How long is it before the URL expires and how do you know it is an expiration causing your problem?  I don't see the Google API docs mentioning this.  Also, what Exception is thrown.  Could you catch it server side and send the user back to the same page, with a newly generated upload URL.  I know this does not fulfil your requirement for the user to not know this has happened.

I guess one option is to find out how long until the URL expires and then use JavaScript to asynchronously call your server near the timeout, retrieve a new upload URL and change the URL in the DOM.

However, the solution to catch the Exception and re-render sounds best, as I imagine the URL should only expire after the user has been idle for a fairly lengthy amount of time?

Comment: I don't know where the exception is, it seems it is on the Blobstore side.  http://temporary-blobstore-error.appspot.com/ that is the page I am being brought to.  I can not recreate this problem on the development server.

Comment: @Lumpy I think we need to get to the bottom of your problem.  You can view the logs in your dashboard at appengine.google.com - can you log into there and provide an extract in your question of what error is being thrown i.e. stacktrace.

Comment: There is no error on my side, the error is on the blobstore side.  My handler never gets called because blobstore never returns.  I looked in the logs and there is no exception for upload or the form page.

Comment: Oh sorry you're getting redirected to the error site.  And this only happens when you leave the page idle before uploading the file?  Google Groups seems littered with folk saying blobstore is unreliable, due to redirecting to that site.  It's not good that Google aren't giving you some indication of what the problem is.

Comment: That seems to be the case with Google. Some of their services are great others like blobstore and their cart API are terrible.  It seems they have very small audiences they cater to and if you aren't that audience you are pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I've seen websites refresh sections of the page without actually refreshing the page. Twitter is one of the nest example is which it loads the latest content to the top of the page without refreshing it.

[According to this website](http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=16) you can fetch dynamic content via xml and php without refreshing the page. So if the form for uploading the images has a timed limit on it you could try a function like this to refresh the form without actually refreshing the page.

Now if the url has a limited time or the page over all has a cookie, you'll need to figure out a way to either renew or extent the cookie which the API may or may not let you do based on how google sets that up.

I guess if worst comes to worst you can just try an auto refresh on the page via an html function, but if the person is in the middle of uploading images and the page refreshes they'll probably lose all of their progress.

Sorry if this isn't the most helpful thing, but I figured I'd try to give some input as to maybe how to get the ball rolling.