# Google app engine blobstore upload url expire

Tags: jquery, python, file-upload, blobstore

I am trying to have a webpage with a file upload box. However, the default type of uploading url will expire in about 10 minutes. I am thinking of ways to prevent that.

[Stop Blob URL from expiring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203089/stop-blob-url-from-expiring)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-fileupload/W6-8rJXgq50

This two suggests a way of using jquery to fetch the url when the user adds the file. The first url, the user uses java and i use python. Also, it only mentions about JQuery side whereas on the python side i do not know what to write to achieve this.

Is there anyone who could give me some insights on how to do this in both the html and the python.

Answer (score 0):

Build your form as you normally would, and your backend code as you normally would. At this stage the fact that the URL expires is irrelevant.

Once your form is working and your backend can accept the data without issue, then use javascript to get a fresh url as the form is submitted. The method is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203089/stop-blob-url-from-expiring).