# How to prevent Blobstore upload URL from expiring when uploding large files using Python on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, blobstore

I'm working on a small app that will take very large files from user and upload them to Blobstore, then process them and move them to Google Cloud Storage.

I'm using Python for this and my code is below. Using standard environment with Python2.7

When users add small files they can normally upload the data and the whole workflow goes smooth, however when they load files with sizes more than 1 or 2 GB's then they get the error below

**Error bad request**

**The upload URL has expired.**

The app is a web app that loads the form for them to upload their files. Users will see the form, click the browse button to load their file and then click the submit button to initiate the upload

```py
import os
import urllib
import webapp2
import cgi
import argparse
import datetime
import pprint
import re
import webapp2
import requests
import cloudstorage
import logging

from flask import Flask, request
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    gs_bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload',gs_bucket_name=gs_bucket_name)

    self.response.write('<html>\n<body>\n')
    self.response.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\n'% upload_url)
    self.response.write('<input type="file" name="file" accept=".mp4"><br>\n')
    self.response.write('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>\n')
    self.response.write('</body>\n</html>\n\n')

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    # 'file' is file upload field in the form
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')

    file_infos = self.get_file_infos()
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    file_info = file_infos[0]

    glob_gs_object_name=file_info.gs_object_name[3:]
    glob_filename=upload_files[0].filename

    cloudstorage.copy2(file_info.gs_object_name[3:], '/BUCKET_NAME/'+upload_files[0].filename, metadata=None, retry_params=None)

    try:
        cloudstorage.delete(file_info.gs_object_name[3:])
    except cloudstorage.NotFoundError:
        pass

    self.response.write(complete_upload)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),('/upload', UploadHandler)],debug=True)
```

So what I was looking for was to get the large files uploaded normally and not getting this error...

Answer (score 1):

The uploadUrl expires after about 10 minutes and I've seen that a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203089/stop-blob-url-from-expiring) is creating the URL when the form is submitted using jQuery.

Uploading directly to Cloud Storage is also an option and there is a Storage [client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/index.html) available but it's only supported on the Python 3 runtime.

Comment: Well I already managed to upload files larger than 50GB from a GCP instance, so I know the code above will be able to handle large files but the issue is I'm not getting how to to handle that URL expiration issue...

I also read that Blobstore is to be used when working with large files instead of GCS API, that's the reason I went with Blobstore... So I guess I'm wrong on this?

What is the maximum size I can upload with the Cloud Storage library linked above?

Comment: I will do another version of the app using Python3 and the Storage client library and hopefully it will work for me. Will update after I implement a basic code to do the upload...